# If statement and sequential execution

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a very short (and pretty much noob) question. I have a function that includes:

```
void function(int x)
{
    x = 3;
    if (x == 4)
        printf("HI!");
    x = 4;
}
```

Will the word `HI!` be printed? In other words, is a C program read sequentially or not?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you compile that and see for yourself?

Comment: C is a procedural language; blocks of code run from top to bottom, sequentially.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - not always great advice in C :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the code compiles to a sequence of instructions which happen sequentially one after the other. The comparison to `4` will always before the assignment `x = 4`. So it will be false.

This type of order is guaranteed when you are dealing with a single thread. When you have multiple threads you can get strange results and race-conditions unless you are careful.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be printed.  The line above is what matters of course.